# How to ajax refresh one row in a view

Tags: views, ajax

Views are often used to modify entities (for example tasks and their status or priorities) and when a field is changed using an ajax button, a page or view refresh is required to update the rest (like row visibilithy, color, or other dependent fields).
Page or views refresh is not userfriendly, it creates a distracting interruption while the attention is drawn away from the field in question. Ideally only the row should be refreshed.

Is row refresh possible and if yes, how?